# Does Wear OS have a concept of a system-level assistant app?

Tags: android, wear-os, google-assistant-sdk

My Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 Classic has a behavior where I can hold down one of the buttons to launch a voice assistant. When I got the watch, this was Bixby, Samsung's assistant app, but a later update added the ability to configure the app to launch the Google Assistant instead.

Is this functionality an affordance built into Wear OS, or my watch's firmware? Is it possible for me to write a Wear OS app that offers assistant functionality and can hook into this same action to trigger the app?